# CmisObjectNotFoundException : Repository does not exist

Tags: java, ear, cmis, documentum, opencmis

Using a CMISTestClient, I am trying to connect with documentum repository. There are no exceptions at weblogic server logs(having server at localhost, where ear is deployed) but my standalone client is throwing exception as CmisObjectNotFoundException : Repository does not exist. Client implementation is as below. Need help, so that a session is created with the repository. Also, the repository(hosted on different server, not localhost) already exist in documentum with same id as used in below session parameters.

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.api.CmisObject;
import org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.api.Document;
import org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.api.Folder;
import org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.api.ItemIterable;
import org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.api.Repository;
import org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.api.Session;
import org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.api.SessionFactory;
import org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.client.runtime.SessionFactoryImpl;
import org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.commons.PropertyIds;
import org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.commons.SessionParameter;
import org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.commons.data.ContentStream;
import org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.commons.data.RepositoryCapabilities;
import org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.commons.data.RepositoryInfo;
import org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.commons.enums.BindingType;
import org.apache.chemistry.opencmis.commons.enums.VersioningState;

public class CMISClientTests {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Start now ");
        
        
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = SessionFactoryImpl.newInstance();
        Map<String, String> parameter = new HashMap<String, String>();
         
        
        parameter.put(SessionParameter.USER, "weblogic");
        parameter.put(SessionParameter.PASSWORD, "weblogic11g");        
        parameter.put(SessionParameter.ATOMPUB_URL, "http://ehs-edm-dvst-001.ehs.state.ma.us:53033/cmis/resources"); 
        
    
        parameter.put(SessionParameter.BINDING_TYPE, BindingType.ATOMPUB.value());
        
        parameter.put(SessionParameter.REPOSITORY_ID, "repos_test_qa");
        Session session = sessionF`enter code here`actory.createSession(parameter);
    }
    }
```

Comment: Is there a repository with the name `repos_test_qa` on your server?

Comment: @Gagravarr, yes repository is present, as one of colleague is able to connect with same repository using tomcat server. But is there any tool to check if this documentum repository exists?

Comment: May be you can try getting all the repositories first and then connect to the particular repository

Comment: @saurav , its returning no repository although repository is present in  server.

Comment: What do you get if you login through the CMIS workbench ?...do you get the repository there ?

Answer (score 1):

Have you configured dfc.properties on cmis deployment? Does http://ehs-edm-dvst-001.ehs.state.ma.us:53033/cmis/ show something? It looks like either a mis-configuration of the emc-cmis' dfc.properties or a communication problem between weblogic and Documentum

Anyway you have to see some error on Weblogic's logs, as CMIS implementation by Opentext runs DFC under the hood, so the DFC errors are there